# Merging iOS .dylib into framework with lipo breaks bitcode recompilation

Tags: ios, frameworks, dynamic-library, bitcode, lipo

I'm trying to build a dynamic iOS framework manually from `.dylib` files. Binaries are created with cmake and xcodebuild and produce two `.dylib` files, one containing `armv7`, `armv7s` and `arm64` and the other `x86_64` and `i386` architectures. Libraries are compiled with `-fembed-bitcode parameter` and everything succeeds.

.dylib files are then merged with next command:

```
lipo -create lib_arm.dylib lib_i386.dylib -output MyFramework
```

Framework is then created by copying the output from lipo command to:

```
MyFramework.framework/MyFramework
```

Headers and `Info.plist` are manually generated and added to the framework.

This framework is then installed via CocoaPods into the application as a `vendored_framework`. It is known that CocoaPods will strip the i386/x86_64 libraries from any fat binaries, for App Store distribution.

**Application builds, runs, archives and uploads successfully to App Store.**

However, since Bitcode is enabled, App Store will process the .ipa, and recompile with bitcode, this is where it fails and I receive an email from App Store, that it failed processing. Following instructions, I can reproduce the error locally with Exporting for Ad-Hoc Distribution and recompiling for bitcode. The error I receive is this:

```
ipatool failed with an exception: #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /lib_arm.dylib>\n
```

So apparently during the recompilation, there is still a reference or somewhere to `lib_arm.dylib`, even though it was merged into a fat dylib Mach-O universal binary (`file` output of the merged dylib binary below):

```
>> file MyFramework
MyFramework: Mach-O universal binary with 5 architectures: [x86_64: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64] [i386] [arm_v7] [arm_v7s] [arm64]
MyFramework (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
MyFramework (for architecture i386):    Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
MyFramework (for architecture armv7):   Mach-O dynamically linked shared library arm_v7
MyFramework (for architecture armv7s):  Mach-O dynamically linked shared library arm_v7s
MyFramework (for architecture arm64):   Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64
```

This is pretty much where my compiler/linker knowledge gets out of scope.
So my question is:

**Where am I going wrong with this? Maybe bitcode should be compiled differently? Or maybe I am using `lipo` in wrong way?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After inspecting load commands of the created fat binary with `otool -l` command, I realized that using `lipo` itself does not change the `LC_ID_DYLIB` in the binary and it will reuse one from the first provided library. Using `install_name_tool` to change the id to correct one of the framework (including `@rpath` for iOS dynamic frameworks) fixes the error.

```
install_name_tool -id @rpath/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework MyFramework
```

Make sure the entire path to binary is included, together with `.framework` directory.